# Oracle GroupBy and Orderby issue

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

I have a query I need to summarize every vm by customer_name, tier_name, vm_name Thus each vm_will output a summarized list of storage tiers it uses with their usages

```
so if vm1 is using tier1 and tier2 belonging to Customer1 entries are like so,

tier1.entry=100
tier1.entry2=100

tier2.entry1 = 50
tier2.entery1 = 40
```

that way each returned sum total would output like so:

CUSTOMER1 VM1 Tier1 Total = 200
CUSTOMER1 VM1 Tier2 Total = 90

, but it gives me this error:

```
SQL> select customer_name,
  2  tier_name,
  3  substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || '/' || vm_display_name),1,100) vm_name,
sum(provisioned_gb) Provisioned_GB,
sum(consumed_gb) Consumed_GB
from customers a,
vm_groups b,
vms c,
vm_storage_histories d,
datastores e,
storage_tiers f
  4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12  where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
 13  and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id
 14  and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
 15  and d.datastore_id = e.datastore_id
 16  and e.storage_tier_id = f.storage_tier_id
 17  and trunc(d.datetime) = to_date('01-Aug-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
 18  and a.customer_id != 24   -- enki
 19  and a.customer_id != 1    -- unassigned
 20  group by customer_name,tier_name, vm_name
 21  order by 1,2,3
 22
SQL> /
substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || '/' || vm_display_name),1,100) vm_name,
              *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Here is my Query:

```
select customer_name,
tier_name,
substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || '/' || vm_display_name),1,100) vm_name,
sum(provisioned_gb) Provisioned_GB,
sum(consumed_gb) Consumed_GB
from customers a,
vm_groups b, 
vms c, 
vm_storage_histories d,
datastores e,
storage_tiers f
where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id
and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
and d.datastore_id = e.datastore_id
and e.storage_tier_id = f.storage_tier_id
and trunc(d.datetime) = to_date('01-Aug-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
and a.customer_id != 24   -- enki
and a.customer_id != 1    -- unassigned
group by customer_name,tier_name, vm_name
order by 1,2,3

/
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create an aggregate query (using GROUP BY), every item in the SELECT statement must either be something in your GROUP BY statement or an aggregate function (SUM, MAX, AVG, etc).

In your example, "substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || '/' || vm_display_name),1,100)" is not listed in the GROUP BY statement, so you get an error.  Easily fixed - add that code exactly as it's written in SELECT to GROUP BY and it should work.

```
group by customer_name,tier_name, vm_name,
         substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || '/' || vm_display_name),1,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with statement as (select customer_name  as customer,
tier_name  as tier,
substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || '/' || vm_display_name),1,100) as vm_name,
provisioned_gb as Provisioned_GB,
consumed_gb as Consumed_GB
from customers a,
vm_groups b, 
vms c, 
vm_storage_histories d,
datastores e,
storage_tiers f
where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id
and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
and d.datastore_id = e.datastore_id
and e.storage_tier_id = f.storage_tier_id
and trunc(d.datetime) = to_date('01-Aug-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
and a.customer_id != 24   -- enki
and a.customer_id != 1    -- unassigned
)

select customer,tier,vm_name,sum(Provisioned_GB),sum(Consumed_GB)
from statement
group by  customer,tier,vm_name
order by order by 1,2,3
```